# Sum over specific values

Tags: r, function, survival-analysis

I'm asked to simulate 50 survival times from an exponential distribution with rate 1.

```
n <- 50
Tstar <- rexp(n, rate = 1)
```

Then I have the following quantities:

Y(t) capturing the individuals at risk at time t, i.e.

```
Y <- function(t){sum(Tstar > t)}
```

and S(t) is the Kaplan-Meier estimator

```
S <- function(t)(1 - 1/n * sum(Tstar < t)
```

But how do I define the following function?

[image]

Here Tstar[i] indicates T_i.

Comment: Do you have some inputs to test results? Please add a `set.seed()` since you use a random generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand my mathematical notations, consider `Reduce` + `sapply` to serve as iterator and summation across specific values:

```r
set.seed(4621)

n <- 50
Tstar <- rexp(n, rate = 1)

Y <- function(t) sum(Tstar > t)
S <- function(t) (1 - 1/n * sum(Tstar < t))

sigma_sq <- function(t) {
  Tstar <- Tstar[Tstar < t]
  S(t)^2 * Reduce(`+`, sapply(Tstar, function(T_i) 1/(Y(t)*(T_i)^2)))
}
```